# Dojo Toolbox: Closing the dialog Box

Tags: button, dojo

Is there a way to set a button inside the dojo dialog box and have it close the dialog box it is residing in?

Putting dijits inside of dijits doesn't work, and I can't beleive there isn't a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can put a dijit widget inside another widget. And in a standard Dojo release there's even a test case [Dijit Dialog focus & destroy](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.2.3/dojo-release-1.2.3/dijit/tests/test_Dialog_focusDestroy.html) included that demonstrates closing dialog with a button inside of it. Here's the relevant part:

```
var btn = new dijit.form.Button({ label: "Close" });
dlg.containerNode.appendChild(btn.domNode);

dojo.connect(btn, "onClick", function(){
    console.log("destroying, while visible"); 
    dlg.destroy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, since Dojo 1.7 onwards, the `connect` module has been replaced with [`dojo/on`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#dojo-on). The equivalent of the above is therefore:

```
require(['dojo/on', 'dijit/form/Button'], function (on, Button) {
    // etc

    var btn = new Button({ label: "Close" });
    dlg.containerNode.appendChild(btn.domNode);

    on(btn, "onClick", function(){
        console.log("destroying, while visible"); 
        dlg.destroy();
    });
});
```